# I am using fakeAsync and tick in unit test case of angular , getting error 2 periodic timer(s) still in the queue

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

i m quiet new to unit testing in angular, getting error Periodic timer still in queue, Please check below code, i tried discardPeriodicTasks(), did not work for me

```
it('navigate to "" redirects you to /orders', fakeAsync(() => {
    tick(15000);
    router.navigate([""]).then(() => {
      expect(location.path()).toBe("/home");
    });
  }));
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try like this.
navigate method resolves true if navigation succees, resolves false if navigation fails , rejects if an error happens.

```
it('test', fakeAsync(() => {
    const router = TestBed.get(Router);
    router.navigate(['']).then(stat => {
      expect(stat).toBeTruthy();
    })
    tick(1500)
  }))
```